# Thread While True: Loop Keeps the Code From Iterating

Tags: python, loops, thread-safety

I have a thread running as a daemon.

In this thread I wish to continously update some variables, that are dependent on reading rows from a MySQL database.

Problem is, that the program doesn't want to iterate past the While True:-loop, although it is inside of a thread. Isn't that the whole point with a thread: That I can have two loops running simultaneously?

```
import threading
import tkinter as tk
import pip
import time
import mysql.connector
from time import sleep

global score
global countdown

en = 1
score = 0
countdown = 1
print("Hiya!")

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="",
    user="",
    password="",
    database='',
    auth_plugin=''
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor(prepared=True)

class Mysql(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True
        self.en = 1
        self.læsTidScoreNu = "SELECT tidSCoreNu FROM bois WHERE id = 1"
        self.læsTidMål = "SELECT tidMål FROM bois WHERE id = 1"
        self.opdaterTidMål = "UPDATE bois SET tidMål = %s WHERE id = %s"
        self.læsStopKnap = "SELECT stopKnap FROM bois WHERE id = 1"
        self.run()

    def run(self) -> None:
        global mycursor
        global mydb

        while True:
            mycursor.execute(self.læsTidScoreNu)
            self.råTidScoreNu = mycursor.fetchone()
            self.tidScoreNu = float("{}".format('%.2f' % self.råTidScoreNu))
            mycursor.execute(self.læsTidMål)
            self.råTidMål = mycursor.fetchone()
            self.tidMål = float("{}".format('%.2f' % self.råTidMål))
            mycursor.execute(self.læsStopKnap)
            self.stopKnap = mycursor.fetchone()



            mydb.commit()



data = Mysql()

print(data.råTidScoreNu)
print(data.tidMål)

forevigt = 0

while (forevigt != 1):
    i = 0.00


    # Servodøren skal åbnes her i denne kode
    while (data.stopKnap != 1):
        # Indtast Pinkoden
        f = int(input(
            "Kodeord - bemærk her, at kodeordene er pinkoderne fra min egen database, bare indtast en værdi mellem 1-6"))
        mycursor.execute("SELECT id,adresse,name,pinkode_brugt,score FROM bois WHERE id=%s", (f,))

        # MySQL Commands
        opdaterSlutScoren = "UPDATE bois SET pinkode_brugt = pinkode_brugt +1, score = %s WHERE id = %s"
        opdaterTidScoreNu = "UPDATE bois SET tidScoreNu = %s WHERE id = %s"
        myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

        row_count = mycursor.rowcount
        print(myresult)
        print("number of affected rows: {}".format(row_count))

        if(f == 1):
            print("ommer")

        else:
            if (row_count == 1):

                # Servomotordøren åbner(function)
                print(row_count)
                print(data.tidScoreNu)
                while (i != data.tidMål) and (i <= data.tidMål) and (data.stopKnap != 1):
                    print('%.2f' % i)
                    i = i + 0.01
                    timeLeft = data.tidScoreNu - i
                    iTwo = data.tidMål
                    countdown = float('%.2f' % i)
                    score = str("{}".format('%.2f' % i))
                    mycursor.execute(opdaterTidScoreNu, (score,en))
                    print("THIS IS X", data.tidMål)
                    time.sleep(0.01)
                    mydb.commit()

                # Hvis spillet stoppes, or i ikke når timerens slutværdi, vil scoren gemmes
                if (i != data.tidScoreNu):
                    # Point bliver tilføjet
                    print(score, i, countdown, myresult)
                    print("Dette er dit resultat: {}".format(score))
                    mycursor.execute(opdaterSlutScoren, (score, f))



                else:
                    # Point bliver tilføjet
                    print("Ingen point")
                    mycursor.execute(opdaterSlutScoren, (score, f))
            if row_count == 0:
                print("fejl!")

            print("Færdig")
            i = 0
            mycursor.execute(opdaterTidScoreNu, ("0", en))
            mydb.commit()

    # Mangler servo-logik, samt en timer
```

Comment: If the thread is doing work, you may need to use multiprocessing. Due to the GIL, you can have multiple threads of execution running "at once", but only bytecode from one thread can execute at a time. Multithreading is really only useful for I/O-bound tasks.

Comment: Threading doesn't really support concurrency for the reasons @Carcigenicate stated — it's more like co-operative multitasking — and therefore isn't well suited for compute-bound tasks which is what it looks like you are trying to do. You might be able to slightly better results by adding a `time.sleep(.1)` within the loop.